# "Empty Bibliography" error when compiling Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

So I have been banging my head against a brick wall literally all day. I have tried 3 different Latex editors (Texmaker, TeXstudio, and Texworks) all on top of MikTex. I have tried copying code from others as well as writing my own, with some extremely basic examples such as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\cite{ref:123}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Where my sample.bib looks like:

```
@book{ref:123,
author = {456},
title = {855},
year = {2464},
}
```

and is saved in the same folder as the Tex file. Any suggestions on how to produce a bibliography would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to Latex!!

The latest:

When I BibTex the document I get this:

[image]

Comment: If your example is exactly as given, your citation key is wrong (`123` in the `.tex` file, `ref:123` in the `.bib` file). Did you also run LaTeX/Biber/LaTeX?

Comment: *"So I have been banging my head against a brick wall literally all day."* That's dangerous! (Don't worry, someone will help you.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Joseph. Apologies that was a mistake when rejigging the code for posting. Have just amended and retried to produce the same result and list of errors. Any other ideas or advice?

Comment: Probably you haven't run `biber`. You'll get the messages about undefined citation and empty bibliography the first time you LaTeX the file, but also a biblatex warning "Please (re)run Biber on the file ... and rerun LaTeX afterwards".

Comment: how do you run biber? is it the same as BibTex? In Texmaker for example I LaTeX -> BibTex -> LaTeX -> LaTeX

Comment: You can try and go to options and there you change the Bib(la)tex command to 'biber %'.
Then after you run pdflatex you go to the pulldown menu at the top and choose the BibTex command. Then click on the arrow left of the pulldown, this should now run biber and create the bibliography.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, PHILIPP. You are a amazing human being been stuck all day i knew it would be something simple but oh so frustrating!! Thank you again

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it worked. But be careful, if you ever go back to bibtex  (I don't think you should but that's my opinion) you would have to change that command back again.